# The cache contains multiple tokens satisfying the requirements

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a react app that calls azure map (graph) and custom api. (currently I'm using react-aad-msal).

I have to use 2 scope one is for the graph and other one is for api.

- https://graph.microsoft.com/.default (graph)
- api://d7eeee58-cd9f-452a-87f3-334ab50b3a2d/readwrite (api)

But when I trying to call to get the access token for each scope, I got this error.

[image: Error]

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: What msal version are you using?  1.4.4 was released 11/11/2020.  Could this solve it?